# Check object for comma separated strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have the following Object in Javascript:

```
{
    birthdate: "25/11/2015",
    coccidiose: "on",
    giardia: "on",
    holiday: "on",
    holidaycountrycheck1: "on",
    holidayenddate: "03/12/2015",
    holidayeurope: "true",
    holidaystartdate: "02/12/2015",
    name: "qsdf",
    treatmentstartdate: "18/11/2015",
    type: "cat",
    vaccinaties: "11/11/2015, 18/11/2015",
    weight: "qsd"
}
```

This object got generated at the submission of a form in the following way:

```
$('.js--submit-form__add-animal').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    dataArray = $(this).closest('form').serializeArray(),
        len = dataArray.length,
        dataObj = {};

    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {

        if(([dataArray[i].name] in dataObj)) {
            dataObj[dataArray[i].name] = dataObj[dataArray[i].name] + ", " + dataArray[i].value;
        } else {
            dataObj[dataArray[i].name] = dataArray[i].value;
        }
    }

    console.log(dataObj);

});
```

As you can see the "vaccinaties" has a comma separated string. I would like to (dynamically) check **dataObj** and change all comma-separatated strings to arrays. What would be the correct approach here?

Comment: Loop through all the properties of the object.  Check if the property value contains "," - split the value on the "," character and assign the resulting array to the property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Loop over object
2. Check if value constant `,`
3. Split by comma to get the array

```js
var obj = {
  birthdate: "25/11/2015",
  coccidiose: "on",
  giardia: "on",
  holiday: "on",
  holidaycountrycheck1: "on",
  holidayenddate: "03/12/2015",
  holidayeurope: "true",
  holidaystartdate: "02/12/2015",
  name: "qsdf",
  treatmentstartdate: "18/11/2015",
  type: "cat",
  vaccinaties: "11/11/2015, 18/11/2015",
  weight: "qsd"
};

// Get array of keys and loop over it
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(e) {
  if (obj[e].indexOf(',') > -1) {
    // If value contains `,` then split it by , with prev/next spaces
    obj[e] = obj[e].split(/\s*,\s*/);
  }
});

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(obj, 0, 4);
console.log(obj);
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: Of course.. I was just thinking about a whole other solution, while the above is crazy obvious. Thank you.